# Phone runs out of memory; reboots

Tags: cyanogenmod, reboot, ram, kernel

Phone is an Alcatel Pixi 4 4034 (which has 512MB RAM).  For various reasons, I've ended up with an unofficial Cyanogenmod 13 port on it.  The problem I have is that the phone periodically slows down and crashes, apparently hanging for a couple of seconds then rebooting.

Doing a bit of digging in the logs, I've found that it's running out of memory immediately prior to the crashes.  I get lots of messages about the ActivityManager terminating various processes, but it clearly isn't enough because when I managed to connect adb during the reboot, I managed to get the following smoking gun from `adb shell dmesg`:

```
[ 4784.206692]  (3)[181:logd.klogd]Out of memory: Kill process 28595 (ndroid.systemui) score 0 or sacrifice child
[ 4784.206715]  (3)[181:logd.klogd]Killed process 28595 (ndroid.systemui) total-vm:761596kB, anon-rss:8552kB, file-rss:0kB
```

This seems to be the root cause of the reboot: systemui is an essential service, and terminating it is going to cause the reboot, and indeed moments later I see:

```
[ 4784.439624]  (0)[1:init]init: Starting service 'bootanim'...
```

Any suggestions how I can prevent this from occurring?  Why is the low memory killer not able to prevent the failure before it happens?

Comment: I had a similar issue here. From what I gather, Android can hit a bit of a wall and not know what to do when it runs out of memory (more commonly with custom ROMS) Android does not cope with it, and can 'wedge' itself, which is a 30 second -5 minute system wide ANR that ends in a reboot. Either that, or Android's memory manager is targeting the zygote process, which begins a quick reboot.